# Button within a custom control loses its event binding when added to a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I built a custom control using the following XAML

```
<StackPanel Name="spTop">
    <Button Name="btnDBConfiguration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" MouseEnter="btnDBConfiguration_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnDBConfiguration_MouseLeave"  >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="/Images/DBImport25px.png" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="imgVerify"></Image>
            <TextBlock Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="tblkConnectionName" >Database</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <!--
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="DBImport">
        <Image Source="/Images/DBImport25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="Database" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>
    </StackPanel>-->
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"  Width="50">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="spButtonBar" MouseEnter="btnDBConfiguration_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnDBConfiguration_MouseLeave" >
            <Button Name="btnDBConnection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ToolTip="DB Connection" Click="btnDBConnection_Click" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image Source="/Images/dbConfig25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="imgDBConnection"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
</StackPanel>
```

The button inside this control works when I manually add this to the canvas with this line:

```
        <Control:dbButtonControl Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

However, when I dynamically add it via drag and drop using this code:

```
        dbButtonControl cntrlDBButton = new dbButtonControl();
        cntrlDBButton.SetNameText(ObjectTitle);
        cntrlDBButton.PreviewMouseDown += CnvsLinkScreen_PreviewMouseDown;

        Canvas.SetLeft(cntrlDBButton, pntEnterPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(cntrlDBButton, pntEnterPoint.Y);

        cnvsLinkScreen.Children.Add(cntrlDBButton);
```

The button within the custom control no longer works.  I have a previewmousedown event added on so I can click and drag the control around the page.  I disabled this event and the button within the control started working again.  So it looks like the preview mouse button event that I added on was causing it.  But I do need to enable that and have the button(s) within the control still work.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a more complex issue that I wanted to try to control with event handling between the app and control.  So what I did was pretty simple...

I created a grid that included my custom control and a "grab" button.

```
        Grid gdTab = new Grid();
        //gdTab.Name = ObjectTitle;
        Image imgGripper = new Image();
        imgGripper.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/images/Dot25px.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        imgGripper.Width = 15;
        imgGripper.Height = 15;
        imgGripper.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        imgGripper.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        imgGripper.MouseEnter += (s,e) => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
        imgGripper.MouseLeave += (s, e) => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        imgGripper.MouseEnter += ImgGripper_MouseEnter;
        imgGripper.MouseLeave += ImgGripper_MouseLeave;

        Canvas.SetLeft(gdTab, pntEnterPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(gdTab, pntEnterPoint.Y);
        gdTab.Children.Add(cntrlDBButton);
        gdTab.Children.Add(imgGripper);
        cnvsLinkScreen.Children.Add(gdTab);
```

I then mapped the MouseEnter and MouseLeave to methods:

```
    private void ImgGripper_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid gdSender = (Grid)((Image)sender).Parent;
        if (gdSender != null)
            gdSender.PreviewMouseDown += CnvsLinkScreen_PreviewMouseDown;
    }
```

and

```
    private void ImgGripper_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid gdSender = (Grid)((Image)sender).Parent;
        if (gdSender != null)
            gdSender.PreviewMouseDown -= CnvsLinkScreen_PreviewMouseDown;
    }
```

That way, the drag option was only available while the mouse was over the small grab area.

I then modified the movement code to move the created Grid with control around.  Once the mouse leave the circle, the control's button will function once again.